# Button event is only selecting the first class. (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to select the saveBtn class on each button so that when I click it it saves it into local storage. However it is only saving the first instance of the selected class. Can anyone help?

html:

```
  <div class="hour-container" id="8am">
    <div class="hour"> 8 AM </div>
    <textarea class="text-content"></textarea>
    <button class="btn saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>
```

js:

```
// Function to save the users input to the text area
function saveText() {
    var textContent = $(".saveBtn").siblings(".text-content").val();
    var hour = $(".saveBtn").parent().attr("id");
    localStorage.setItem(hour, textContent);
    console.log(textContent);
}

// Call saveText on save button click
$(".saveBtn").on("click", saveText);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler, the searching scope of `$(".saveBtn")` is the whole web page.

That means the reference point of all actions is referred to the beginning of the web page.

So, the function `$(".saveBtn")` always refer to the first element which has the `saveBtn` CSS class.

You may modify the `saveText` function as the following:

```
function saveText() {
    var textContent = $(this).siblings(".text-content").val();
    var hour = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    localStorage.setItem(hour, textContent);
    console.log(hour,textContent);
}
```

For my solution, the `this` refers to the element which has been clicked by a user, so the reference point of all actions is referred to the element which has been clicked, therefore it should be work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain why this makes a difference? I am new to Jquery.

Comment: In this case, `this` means the button that triggers the event. So, all the searches are base on the `this` object not from the beginning of the DOM.

Comment: By the way, if my solution works fine, would you give me a tick?

Comment: Please add your description of why this works, what the problem was, what you changed, etc to your answer.  As OP already pointed out, just a chunk of code does not help anyone *understand*.  [Code-only answers are considered low quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).